# Can I pass an async delegate to IMvxMessenger.SubscribeOnMainThread()?

Tags: xamarin, async-await, mvvmcross

I'm using Xamarin and Mvvmcross to write an Android app. I have a situation where I'm using an IMvxMessenger message to kick off some work. The work involves some async tasks which I'm "await"ing. Is this ok?  Example is like the code below.

```
    Mvx.Resolve<IMvxMessenger>().SubscribeOnMainThread<AndroidEmailServiceStartedMessage>
        (
            async msg => 
            {
                    await DoDownloadRequests(CurrentRequests);
            }
        );
```

Comment: Yes, but that delegate is not being awaited because it's an async void. It just returns after being called.

Comment: Also you never save the token for the subscription.

Comment: Thanks for both comments. The token saving (just an oversight) turned out to be the root of my problem. Every day we learn a little more....